# Android: How to read a file from the Internet using coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to read a file located at a certain URL. I created such a function:

```
private fun urlRead() {
    val url = URL(MY_URL)
    val stream = url.openStream()
    val v = stream.read()
}
```

And I call this function from onCreate. But it throws exception NetworkOnMainThreadException. Android requires applications to work with networks from other thread. Documentations recommends to use coroutines for simple multithreading tasks. But I cannot find good example of using coroutines in Kotlin in Android.

Can you give a short code example with code above using coroutines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all:
It will be easier if you use Lifecycle api:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

If you make the request from an activity, you can use "lifecyclescope"
If you make from viewModel, you can use viewModelScope

Since a request may take a while to finish, you can't do it from the Main thread. You should use IO.

So, for exemple, if you use a viewModel:

```
class MyViewModel(): ViewModel() {
//some code

fun urlRead() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        //here you make the requests
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My activity does not have a member lifecycleScope or viewModelScope. How to add it?

Comment: @AndreyEpifantsev You need to add lifecycle dependency.

On you build.gradle(app) add the following line on dependencies:
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

Sync gradle

Now you may be able to call "lifecycleScope" on your fragment with:
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
}

You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is launch it within a coroutine context, like this

```
private suspend fun urlRead() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val url = URL(MY_URL)
    val stream = url.openStream()
    stream.read()
}
```

then you call it like this

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val v = urlRead()
    // TODO; use v
}
```

See [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) for reference.

Comment: Compilation errors: "Unresolved reference: lifecycleScope", "Unresolved reference: withContext", "Unresolved reference: Dispatchers". Alt-Enter does not fix these errors automatically.

Comment: I added a link to the response.

Comment: In the document, the link to which you added, there are three options for adding dependencies. Which one to choose? I want to use CoroutineScope in Activity as described here: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/.

Answer (score 0):

i find this coroutines tutorial quite clear and easy to digest https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html

short code example

```
 private fun urlRead() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val url = URL(MY_URL)
        val stream = url.openStream()
        val v = stream.read()
    }
}
```

Dispatchers.IO means the thread on the bracket code will run in background thread
for more on that read this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html

Comment: Compilation errors: "Unresolved reference: GlobalScope", "Unresolved reference: Dispatchers", Alt-Enter does not fix these errors automatically.

Comment: add on your project gradle : implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'